# ExtJS 3.4.0 GridView body and header have different width

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs3

How can I fit GridView body width to header with? Screencast with bad bahavior is [here](http://vimeo.com/147080639)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've found desision. The **scrollOffset** setting of the GridView component is that what I need!